# Managing two current users with sessions

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, session

What I am trying to do is allow admin users to browse the website as other users in a "new window". This works perfectly and everything is fine and dandy until the admin decides to return to the original window, which believes that the admin is now the other user of the "new window".

What I guess I want to do is create a new session for the "new window". So how do I go about doing this?

The current implementation of the functionality is a button on the admin page that jumps to an Action in AccountController that subsequently performs the LogOn for the user that the admin wants to browse. I am using MVC2 and .aspx.

Any responses are appreciated! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a solution that's going to get exactly what you want here.  Consider that the browser is storing a cookie identifying your current session.  It's only going to store one cookie for the website, meaning that if you're logging in as another user, you have effectively overwritten the previous session.

My suggestion would be to add an additional function to your AccountController that allows admins to log in as users.  The responsibility of this is to create a cookie value that effectively identifies that the user has just left a previous session.

Here's an article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FormsUserImpersonation.aspx) that does what you're trying to do, albeit in ASP.NET and not MVC.  I'm sure the code can be easily adapted, though.

Comment: Thanks that was the inspiration I needed! There were some MVC conversions in the article comments, though they needed some modifications to work with my code. A billion thanks villecoder!